# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'POLLIN' in micropython script

Tags: python, embedded, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, micropython

whenever i try to run the captive portal script i begins to work by creating the AP and configuring the servers but once it is about to start printing http request it cast this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "main.py", line 5, in 
File "captive_portal.py", line 70, in start
File "captive_portal.py", line 106, in captive_portal
File "captive_portal.py", line 121, in handle_http
File "captive_http.py", line 32, in handle
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'POLLIN'

so here is my captive portal script

```
import network
import ubinascii as binascii
import uerrno
import uos as os
import urandom
import utime as time
import gc 
import uselect as select
from captive_dns import DNSServer
from captive_http import HTTPServer


banner = '''
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡾⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠰⣶⡀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡿⠁⣴⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠸⣦⠈⢿⡄⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⡇⢸⡏⢰⡇⠀⠀⢸⡆⢸⡆⢸⡇⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢹⡇⠘⣧⡈⠃⢰⡆⠘⢁⣼⠁⣸⡇⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢿⣄⠘⠃⠀⢸⡇⠀⠘⠁⣰⡟⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⠃⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠘⠋⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠀
⠀⢸⣿⣟⠉⢻⡟⠉⢻⡟⠉⣻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠀
⠀⢸⣿⣿⣷⣿⣿⣶⣿⣿⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠀
⠀⠈⠉⠉⢉⣉⣉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⣉⣉⡉⠉⠉⠁⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠉⠀⠀⠀v1.1⠀

'''
COLOR_GREEN = '\033[92m'
COLOR_RED = '\033[91m'
COLOR_RESET = '\033[0m'


print(COLOR_GREEN + banner)


class CaptivePortal():
    AP_IP = "210.210.210.1"
    SERVER_SUBNET = '255.255.255.0'
    
    

    def __init__(self, essid = None):
        self.SERVER_IP = self.AP_IP
        self.SUBNET = self.SERVER_SUBNET
        self.sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        self.ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)

        if essid is None:
            essid = "FAKEAP" #access point name
        self.essid = essid  

        # Generate a random MAC address (for anonymity) (vendor is 'Cambium Networks.')
        mac = bytearray([0x7f, 0x16, 0x3e, urandom.getrandbits(8), urandom.getrandbits(8), urandom.getrandbits(8)])
        mac_string = ':'.join('%02x' % i for i in mac)
        self.mac = mac_string

        self.dns_server = None
        self.http_server = None
        self.poller = select.poll()  

        


    def start(self):
        #turn off station interface to force reconnect
        self.sta_if.active(False)
        #if not self.try_connect_from_file():
        self.captive_portal()


    def start_access_point(self):

        #sometimes need to turn off AP before it comes up properly
        self.ap_if.active(False)
        while not self.ap_if.active():
            print(COLOR_RED + "Waiting for access Point To turn on")
            self.ap_if.active(True)
            time.sleep(4)
        #setup a DNS server to redirect all connected clients Traffic
        self.ap_if.ifconfig((self.SERVER_IP, "255.255.255.0", self.SERVER_IP, self.SERVER_IP))  
        self.ap_if.config(essid=self.essid, authmode=network.AUTH_OPEN, channel= int(6))
        print(COLOR_GREEN + "[Wi-Fi] Wireless AP is active, ESSID: {}".format(self.essid))
        print(COLOR_GREEN + "[AP mode] Configured:", self.ap_if.ifconfig())


    def captive_portal(self):
        print("starting captive portal") 
        self.start_access_point()
        if self.http_server is None:
            self.http_server = HTTPServer(self.poller, self.SERVER_IP)
            print("[HTTP] server configured")
        if self.dns_server is None:
            self.dns_server = DNSServer(self.poller, self.SERVER_IP)
            print("[DNS] Server has been Configured")

        try:
            while True:
                gc.collect()
                #check for socket events and handle them
                for response in self.poller.ipoll(1000):
                    sock, event, *others = response
                    is_handled = self.handle_dns(sock, event, others)
                    if not is_handled:
                        self.handle_http(sock, event, others)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Captive portal stopped")
            self.cleanup()

    def handle_dns(self, sock, event, others):
        if sock is self.dns_server.sock:
            #ignore UDP sockets  hangup
            if event == select.POLLHUP:
                return True
                self.dns_server.handle(sock, event, others)
                return True
            return False

    def handle_http(self, sock, event, others):
        self.http_server.handle(sock, event, others)

            

    def cleanup(self):
        print("cleaning up")
        if self.dns_server:
            self.dns_server.stop(self.poller)
        gc.collect()
```

and this is my captive_http script

```
import usocket as socket
from server import Server
from uselect import select
import uerrno
import uio
import gc
from collections import namedtuple
WriteConn = namedtuple("WriteConn", ["body", "buff", "buffmv", "write_range"])

class HTTPServer(Server):
    def __init__(self, poller, local_ip):
        super().__init__(poller, 80, socket.SOCK_STREAM, "HTTP Server")
        if type(local_ip) is bytes:
            self.local_ip = local_ip
        else:
            self.local_ip = local_ip.encode()
        self.request = dict()
        self.conns = dict()


        # queue up to 5 connection request before refusing
        self.sock.listen(5)
        self.sock.setblocking(False)


    def handle(self, sock, event, others):
        if sock is self.sock:
            # client connection on port 80, so spawn off a new
            # socket to handle this connection
            print("- Accepting new HTTP connection")
            self.accept(sock)
        elif event & select.POLLIN:
            # sock has data to read in 
            print("- Reading Incoming [HTTP] data")
            self.read(sock)
        elif event & select.POLLOUT:
            # existing connection has space to send more data
            print("- Sending Outgoing [HTTP] data")  
            self.write_to(sock)  

    def accept(self, server_sock):
        """ accept a new client request socket and register it for polling """

        try:
            client_sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
        except OSError as e:
            if e.args[0] == uerrno.EAGAIN:
                return

        client_sock.setblocking(False)
        client_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.poller.register(client_sock, select.POLLIN)


    def read(self, s):
        """ read in client request from socket """

        data = s.read()
        if not data:
            # no data in the TCP stream, so close the socket
            self.close(s)
            return

        # add new data to the full request 
        sid = id(s)  
        self.request[sid] = self.request.get(sid, b"") + data

        # Check if this is a proper HTTP request
        if data[-4:] != b"\r\n\r\n":
            # HTTP request is not finished if no blank line at the end
            # wait for next read event on this socket instead
            return

        # Get the completed requested 
        req = self.request.pop(sid)


        print("Client Raw Request:\n", req)

        #send a temorary 404 response
        headers  = b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n"
        body = uio.BytesIO(b"")
        self.prepare_write(s, body, headers)

    def prepare_write(self, s, body, headers):
        # add newline to header to signify transition to body
        headers += "\r\n"
        # TCP/IP MSS is MSS 536 bytes, so create buffer of this size initially populate with header data
        buff = bytearray(headers + "\x00" * (536 - len(headers)))
        #save place for next write event
        c = WriteConn(body, buff, buffmv, [0, len(headers) + bw])
        self.conns[id(s)] = c
        # let the poller know we want to know whenit is okay to write
        self.poller.modify(s, select.POLLOUT)


    def write_to(self, sock):
        """ write the message to an open socket """
        #get the data that needs to be written to this socket
        c = self.conns[id(sock)]
        if c:
            # Write next 536 bytes (max) into the socket
            bytes_written = sock.write(
                c.buffmv[c.write_range[0] : c.write_range[1]]
            )     
            if not bytes_written or c.write_range[1] < 536:
                # either we wrote no bytes, or we wrote < TCP MSS of bytes
                # so we're done with this connection
                self.close(sock)
            else:
                # more to write, so read the next portion of the data into
                # the memoryview for the next send event
                self.buff_advance(c, bytes_written)



    def buff_advance(self, c, bytes_written):
        """advance the writer buffer for this connection to next outgoing bytes"""

        if bytes_written == c.write_range[1] - c.write_range[0]:
            # wrote all the bytes we had buffered into the memoryview
            # set next write start on the memoryview to the beginning
            c.write_range[0] = 0 
            # set next write end on the memoryview to length of bytes
            # read in from remainder of the body, up to TCP MSS
            c.write_range[1] = c.body.readinto(c.buff, 536)
        else:
            # didn't read in all the bytes that were in the memoryview
            # so just set next write start to where we ended the write
            c.write_range[0] += bytes_written



    def close(self, s):
        """close the socket, unregister from poller, and delete connection """

        s.close()
        self.poller.unregister(s)
        sid = id(s)
        if sid in self.request:
            del self.request[sid]
        if sid in self.conns:
            del self.conns[sid]
        gc.collect()
```

here is my server script

```
import usocket as socket
import uselect as select

class Server:
    def __init__(self, poller, port, sock_type, name):
        self.name = name
        # create socket with correct type : stream (TCP) or datagrams (UDP)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, sock_type)


        #register to get event update for this socket
        self.poller = poller
        self.poller.register(self.sock, select.POLLIN)

        addr = socket.getaddrinfo("0.0.0.0", port) [0] [-1]
        #allow new request while sending last response
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(addr)


        print(self.name , " Server listening on ", addr, "/udp")


    def stop(self, poller):
        poller.unregister(self.sock)
        self.sock.close()
        print(self.name, "stopped")
```

and finally this is my captive_dns script

```
import usocket as socket
import gc

from server import Server

class DNSServer(Server):
    def __init__(self, poller, ip_addr):
        super().__init__(poller, 53, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, "[DNS]")
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr

    def handle(self, sock, event, others):
        # server doesn't spawn other sockets, so only respond to its own socket
        if sock is not self.sock:
            return

        # check the DNS question, and respond with an answer
        try:
            data, sender = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            request = DNSQuery(data)
            print("[DNS] Replying: {:s} -> {:s}".format(request.domain, self.ip_addr))
            sock.sendto(request.answer(self.ip_addr), sender)

            #help with memory management
            del request
            gc.collect()
        except Exception as e:
            print("DNS server exception:", e)

class DNSQuery:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.domain = ""
        #header is bytes 0-11, soquestion starts on byte 12
        head = 12
        #length of this label defined in first byte
        length = data[head]
        while length != 0:
            label = head + 1
            #add the label to the requested domain and insert a Dot after
            self.domain += data[label : label + length].decode("utf-8") + "."
            #check if thereis anoter label after this one 
            head += length + 1
            length = data[head]            


    def  answer(self, ip_addr):
        #  ** create the answer header **
        # copy the ID from incoming request 
        packet =self.data[:2]
        # set response flags (assume RD =1 from request)
        packet += b"\x81\x80"
        #copy Over QDcount and set ANDcount equal
        packet += self.data[4:6] + self.data[4:6]
        #set NScount and ARCOUNT to 0
        packet += b"\x00\x00\x00\x00"

        # ** create the answer body
        #respond with original domain name question
        packet += self.data[12:]
        #pointer back to domain name (at byte 12)
        packet += b"\xC0\x0C"
        #set type and class
        packet += b"\x00\x01\x00\x01"
        #set TTL to 60sec
        packet += b"\x00\x00\x00\x3C"
        # set response length to 4 byte (to hold one IPV4 address)
        packet += b"\x00\x04"
        #now actually send the IP address as 4 bytes (without the "."s)
        packet += bytes(map(int, ip_addr.split(".")))


        gc. collect()

        return packet
```

so please i would need help to fix this error in this code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

Change

`import uselect as select`

to be

`import uselect as select, POLLIN`

and change `select.POLLIN` to be just `POLLIN`

Explanation:

POLLIN is defined as part of `uselect`, not `uselect.select()`. You can use the `help()` function to see what is defined where.

To show what's included with the select function:

```
>>> from uselect import select
>>> help(select)
object <function> is of type function
```

To show what's included with the uselect module:

```
>>> import uselect
>>> help(uselect)
object <module 'uselect'> is of type module
  __name__ -- uselect
  select -- <function>
  poll -- <function>
  POLLIN -- 1
  POLLOUT -- 4
  POLLERR -- 8
  POLLHUP -- 16
```